# gem を使ってインストールしようとするとエラー: cannot load such file - mkmf (LoadError)

Tags: ubuntu, rubygems

[Sphero を Scratch から動かせるようにしたのでこどもでもプログラミングできるよ](http://blog.champierre.com/1029)

SpheroとUbuntuにインストールしたScratch1.4を接続しようと思い、上記のブログ記事を参考にコマンドを実行したが、エラーが出ます。解決方法を教えてください。

**実行したコマンド**

```
sudo gem install hybridgroup-serialport
```

**エラーメッセージ**

```
Fetching: hybridgroup-serialport-1.2.1.gem (100%)
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing hybridgroup-serialport:
ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
/usr/bin/ruby1.9.1 extconf.rb
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require': cannot load such file -- mkmf (LoadError)
from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
from extconf.rb:1:in `<main>'

Gem files will remain installed in /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/hybridgroup-serialport-1.2.1 for inspection.
Results logged to /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/hybridgroup-serialport-1.2.1/ext/native/gem_make.out
```

環境: Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: `Failed to build gem native extension` の後もエラーは続いていますよね？そちらも貼っていただけないでしょうか。（例 http://kzy52.com/entry/2014/11/09/000511）

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。
元の質問にエラーをすべてコピペしました。よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: [mkmfが無い場合はruby-devをインストール](http://www.xmisao.com/2014/07/06/cannot-load-such-file-mkmf.html)

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。
sudo apt-get install ruby-dev
を実行してから
sudo gem install hybridgroup-serialport
とすることで無事にインストールできました。

Answer (score 1):

以下のブログ記事を参考に、まず **ruby-dev** パッケージをインストールしてから
質問に記載した `gem` コマンドを実行することで無事にインストールできました。

**参考:**
[mkmfが無い場合はruby-devをインストール](https://www.xmisao.com/2014/07/06/cannot-load-such-file-mkmf.html)

> ```
> $ sudo apt-get install ruby-dev
> ```

---

*この投稿は [@takashin10 さんのコメント](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/10260/gem%E3%82%92%E4%BD%BF%E3%81%A3%E3%81%A6%E3%82%A4%E3%83%B3%E3%82%B9%E3%83%88%E3%83%BC%E3%83%AB%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B%E3%81%A8%E3%82%A8%E3%83%A9%E3%83%BC%E3%81%8C%E3%81%A7%E3%82%8B#comment9460_10260) の内容を元に コミュニティwiki として投稿しました。*